# How to retain cart item history after logged out in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a requirement to insert items from a temporary table to codeigniter cart session. Because, I don't want to loose cart session data every time when user logged out. Instead of that when ever a user logged in his previous cart items should be shown if he intentionally didnot delete them.
Thanks

Comment: i think you should used cookies OR to store data into database and also this platform is not a free source code provider, do some effort or google

Comment: You can also store the cart info in local storage until the user either empties the cart or finish the transaction. So, if you should use cookies/database/local storage is 100% up to you and not something we can decide for you. That's why I'm voting to close this question as "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Thanks Magnus for your valuable opinion, but I have to provide the user  the cart history from any other machine too.

Comment: Then I don't really get what the question here is? Just store the cart in a table (with the user ID) until they empties it/finish the transaction? Then it will still be there when the user logs in again.

Comment: You mean to say instead of CI cart session, all transactions from temporary tables.

Comment: insert all data in to a database... create a `MY_Cart` Class and extend it from `CI_Cart` and overwrite the necessary functions - i can't say more to that manner because you've to show @least some effort in order to get help here. Needless to say - but this library is deprecated so you shouldn't use it anymore... take a look here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/cart.html

Answer (score 0):

You can save the cart items to database for particular user and when user logged out unset all user info from session except userid (**Don't check islogged in by session user id** ) and fetch the cart contents from database using that id .

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that the CI_Cart library is marked as deprecated, so if this is a long term project that you expect to maintain for a while you might want to just use another library.

If you still want to use the cart library, my advise is to create a table in your database that has the same structure as your cart_contents session array.

After that you might want to extend the CI_Cart library and add the ability to save the data there at the same time it is saved in session. Same thing goes for all the other operations: removing items, adding new ones etc.

After that you just go to your login function and every time a user logs into your site you query that table and check if there is any cart still available. If so, just populate your session with the cart_contents and the user will have access to that cart that he left behind.